# Print Specific worksheet in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, printing

I have a c# function that prints an excel file from it's path. The excel file contains multiple worksheet and I want to be able to select which worksheet to print

```
private void PrintExcelDocument()
{
    var process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        Verb = "print",
        FileName = Path,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    process.Start();

    // Fermer le processus s'il est encore ouvert
    if (!process.HasExited)
    {
        process.WaitForExit(5000);
    }

    process.Close();
}
```

How can I specify if I want to print all worksheets or one specific ? At the moment, it prints the last one that was opened (when I last saved the file).

I tried adding `Arguments` with the workbook name but no luck. Also, I haven't found any documentation regarding Excel printing from process. I know I can use Microsoft's dll for Excel (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`) but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not like to use Excel Interop COM then this might be helpful to you considering that you are working with .xlsx file format.

1. If you open an excel file with Hex-editor you will notice that the file signature is PK(zip file format), meaning that it is basically zipped XML files.
2. Thus, you can just right click the excel.xlsx file, unzip it and then inside '\xl\worksheets' folder you will see 'sheet[1~10].xml' files
3. Now use the following codes to get all the worksheets

```
using System.IO;
string[] file_arr = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\path\to\files\", "*.xlsx");
```